# Regex to get the string inside parentheses using hive sql

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I am trying to get the string between parentheses but i am getting always getting empty value.

```
String_Input: select sum(OUTPUT_VALUE) from table_name
Output : OUTPUT_VALUE
```

What I tried here:

```
select regexp_extract(String_Input,"/\\(([^)]+)\\)/") from table_name;
```

any suggestion to get the value ?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get the value without the parentheses, you should indicate that you need to extract Captturing group 1 value in the third argument to `regexp_extract` function. Besides, you should remove `/` delimiters, they are parsed as literal symbols.

```
select regexp_extract(String_Input,"\\(([^)]+)\\)", 1) from table_name;
                                    ^            ^  ^
```

From the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF):

> The *'index'* parameter is the Java regex *`Matcher group()`* method index. See *docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html* for more information on the 'index' or Java regex *`group()`* method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\((.*?)\)
```

In Hive:

```
select regexp_extract(String_input,'\\((.*?)\\)')
from table_name
```